# Is there a means of finding an infinite sum by means of altering it into an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

If you are given a sum, say

$$\sum_a^b f(x)$$
 with $a,b\lt \infty$

Is there a means of solving for this sum by means of integration? (I am familiar with sophomores dream.)

Thank you for any help

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula

Comment: Alternatively, look up the Abel-Plana formula.

Comment: @A.S. Interesting, I never really realized it had uses in approximation

Comment: The other possibility is to express the sum as a contour integral, with the summand multiplied by a factor with poles at the right places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{a}^b f(\lceil n\rceil )\text{d}n=\sum_{n=a}^b f(n)$$